# tengo problemas para conectar mysql con python3, al correr el programa solo me lanza errores, son ejemplos básicos, pero no encuentro el problema

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.errors import Error

datos_jefe=""
datos_empleado=""

def AlmacenarArea():
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )      

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion establecida")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            id_area = input("Ingrese ID del area: ")
            nombre_area = input("Ingrese Nombre del area: ")
            sql="INSERT INTO area(id_area, nombre_area) values(%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(id_area, nombre_area))
            conexion.commit()
            
        print("Registro almacenados")      

    except Error as er:
       print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("conexion a BD finalizada")

def AlmacenarCargo():
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )      

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            id_c=input("Id cargo: ")
            nombre_c=input("Nombre cargo: ")
            areaDepartamento_c=input("Area y departamento de cargo: ")
            sql_c="INSERT INTO Cargo(Id_Cargo, Nombre_cargo, Area_Departamento) values(%s,%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql_c(id_c,nombre_c,areaDepartamento_c))
            conexion.commit()
            
        print("Registro almacenados")      

    except Error as er:
       print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("conexion a BD finalizada")


def AlmacenarEmpleado():
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )      

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion establecida")
            print("Ingrese los datos: ")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            rut_e=input("Rut empleado: ")
            nombres_e=input("Nombres empleado: ")
            apellidos_e=input("Apellidos empleado: ")
            sexo_e=input("Sexo empleado: ")
            direccion_e=input("Direccion empleado: ")
            telefono_e=input("Telefono empleado: ")
            fecha_ingreso_c_e=input("Fecha ingreso compañia empleado: ")

            id_cf=input("Id carga familiar: ")
            nombres_cf=input("Nombres carga familiar: ")
            apellidos_cf=input("Apellidos carga familiar: ")
            parentesco_cf=input("Parentesco carga familiar: ")
            sexo_cf=input("Sexo carga familiar: ")

            id_ce=input("Id contacto de emergencia: ")
            nombres_ce=input("Nombres contacto de emergencia: ")
            apellidos_ce=input("Apellidos contacto de emergencia: ")
            relacion_ce=input("Relacion contacto de emergencia: ")
            telefono_ce=input("Telefono contacto de emergencia: ")

            id_c=input("Id cargo: ")
            nombre_c=input("Nombre cargo: ")
            areaDepartamento_c=input("Area y departamento de cargo: ")


            sql_ce="INSERT INTO Contacto_Emergencia(Id_Contacto, Nombres, Apellidos, Relacion, Telefono) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            sql_cf="INSERT INTO Carga_familiar(Id_Carga_Familiar, Nombres, Apellidos, Parentezco, Sexo) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            sql_e="INSERT INTO Empleado(Rut, Nombres, Apellidos, Sexo, Direccion, Telefono, Fecha_Ingreso_Compania) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            sql_c="INSERT INTO Cargo(Id_Cargo, Nombre_cargo, Area_Departamento) values(%s,%s,%s)"

            cursor.execute(sql_ce,(id_ce,nombres_ce,apellidos_ce,relacion_ce,telefono_ce))
            cursor.execute(sql_cf(id_cf,nombres_cf,apellidos_cf,parentesco_cf,sexo_cf))
            cursor.execute(sql_e(rut_e,nombres_e,apellidos_e,sexo_e,direccion_e,telefono_e,fecha_ingreso_c_e))
            cursor.execute(sql_c(id_c,nombre_c,areaDepartamento_c))
            conexion.commit()

            
        print("Registro guardado")      

    except Error as er:
       print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("conexion a BD termiada")


def ConsultarTodo():

    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )    

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT rut_e, nombres_e, sexo_e, direccion_e, telefono_e, fecha_ingreso_c_e FROM trabajador")
            consulta=cursor.fetchall()
            print("RUT     /    Nombre    / Sexo /   direccion     /   telefono  /   fecha ingreso")
            for datos in consulta:
                print(datos[0],"/", datos[1],"/", datos[2],"/",datos[3],"/", datos[4],"/", datos[5])    

    except Error as er:
        print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("Consulta finalizada")


def ConsultarID():

    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )    

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            id=int(input("Ingrese Rut del Trabajador: "))
            sql="SELECT rut_t, nombre_t, sexo_t, direccion_t, telefono_t, cargo_t, fecha_ing, id_contacto_e, id_carga, id_departamento, id_area FROM trabajador WHERE rut_t="+str(id)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            exec=cursor.fetchone()
            print("RUT: ", exec[0])
            print("Nombre: ", exec[1])
            print("Sexo: ", exec[2])
            print("Direccion: ", exec[3])
            print("Telefono: ", exec[4])
            print("Cargo: ", exec[5])
            print("Fecha de ingreso: ", exec[6])
            print("RUT contacto de emergencia: ", exec[7])
            print("RUT carga familiar: ", exec[8])
            print("ID departamento: ", exec[9])
            print("ID area: ", exec[10])
    except Error as er:
        print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("Consulta finalizada") 



def ConsultaFiltrada():

    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )    

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            sex=input("Ingrese Sexo de los trabajadores: ")
            cargo=input("Ingrese Cargo de los trabajadores: ")
            dep=input("Ingrese Departamento: ")
            area=input("Ingrese Area: ")
            sql="SELECT rut_t, nombre_t, sexo_t, cargo_t, nombre_departamento, nombre_area FROM trabajador INNER JOIN departamento ON trabajador.id_departamento=departamento.id_departamento INNER JOIN area ON trabajador.id_area=area.id_area WHERE sexo_t='{}' AND cargo_t='{}' AND nombre_departamento='{}' AND nombre_area='{}'".format(sex, cargo, dep, area)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            exec=cursor.fetchall()
            for datos in exec:
                print(datos[0],"/", datos[1],"/", datos[2],"/",datos[3],"/",datos[4],"/",datos[5]) 
                
                   

    except Error as er:
        print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("Consulta finalizada")



def CambiarDatosPersonales(rut):
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )      

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            direccion = input("Cambiar direccion: ")
            sql="UPDATE trabajador SET direccion_t='{}' WHERE rut_t={}".format(direccion, rut)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            conexion.commit()
            
        print("Registros Actualizados")      

    except Error as er:
       print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("conexion a BD finalizada")


def CambiarDatosLaborales(rut):
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )      

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            cargo = input("Cambiar cargo: ")
            area = input("ID nueva area asignada: ")
            departamento = input("ID nuevo departamento asignado: ")
            sql="UPDATE trabajador SET cargo_t='{}', id_departamento='{}', id_area='{}' WHERE rut_t={}".format(cargo, departamento, area, rut)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            conexion.commit()
            
        print("Registros Actualizados")      

    except Error as er:
       print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("conexion a BD finalizada")


def CambiarContactos(id, id_t):
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )      

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            delet_campo="UPDATE trabajador SET id_contacto_e=NULL WHERE rut_t='{}'".format(id_t)
            cursor.execute(delet_campo)
            delet="DELETE FROM contacto_emergencia WHERE id_contacto_e='{}'".format(id)
            cursor.execute(delet)
            rut = input("RUT nuevo contacto: ")
            nombre = input("Nombre contacto emergencia: ")
            relacion = input("Relacion con trabajador: ")
            telefono = input("Numero de telefono: ")
            sql="INSERT INTO contacto_emergencia(id_contacto_e, nombre_e, relacion_trabajador, numero_telefono_e) values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            sql_u="UPDATE trabajador SET id_contacto_e='{}' WHERE rut_t='{}'".format(rut, id_t)
            cursor.execute(sql,(rut, nombre, relacion, telefono))
            cursor.execute(sql_u)
            conexion.commit()
            
        print("Registros Actualizados")      

    except Error as er:
       print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("conexion a BD finalizada")            


def CambiarCarga(id, id_t):
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )      

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            delet_campo="UPDATE empleado SET id_carga=NULL WHERE rut_t='{}'".format(id_t)
            cursor.execute(delet_campo)
            delet="DELETE FROM cargas_familiares WHERE id_carga='{}'".format(id)
            cursor.execute(delet)
            rut = input("RUT Carga: ")
            nombre = input("Nombre carga: ")
            parentesco = input("Parentesco: ")
            sexo = input("Sexo carga: ")
            sql="INSERT INTO cargas_familiares(id_carga, nombre_c, parentesco, sexo_c) values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            sql_u="UPDATE trabajador SET id_carga='{}' WHERE rut_t='{}'".format(rut, id_t)
            cursor.execute(sql,(rut, nombre, parentesco, sexo))
            cursor.execute(sql_u)
            conexion.commit()
            
        print("Registros Actualizados")      

    except Error as er:
       print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("conexion a BD finalizada") 


def ConsultaActualizar():

    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )    

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            id=int(input("Ingrese Rut del Trabajador: "))
            sql="SELECT rut_t, nombre_t, sexo_t, direccion_t, telefono_t, cargo_t, fecha_ing, id_contacto_e, id_carga, id_departamento, id_area FROM trabajador WHERE rut_t="+str(id)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            exec=cursor.fetchone()
            print("Trabajador")
            print("RUT: ", exec[0])
            print("Nombre: ", exec[1])
            print("Sexo: ", exec[2])
            print("Direccion: ", exec[3])
            print("Telefono: ", exec[4])
            print("Cargo: ", exec[5])
            print("Fecha de ingreso: ", exec[6])
            print("RUT contacto de emergencia: ", exec[7])
            print("RUT carga familiar: ", exec[8])
            print("ID departamento: ", exec[9])
            print("ID area: ", exec[10])
            while True:
                print("""
                ---------------------------------------

                 1- Actualizar Datos personales
                 2- Actualizar Datos laborales
                 3- Actualizar Contactos de emergencia
                 4- Actualizar Carga familiar
                 5- Volver

                --------------------------------------- 
                """)
                opt=int(input("Seleccione opcion: "))
                if opt == 1:
                    CambiarDatosPersonales(exec[0])
                elif opt == 2:
                    CambiarDatosLaborales(exec[0])
                elif opt == 3:
                    CambiarContactos(exec[7], exec[0])
                elif opt == 4:
                    CambiarCarga(exec[8], exec[0])
                elif opt == 5:
                    break                
                    


    except Error as er:
        print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("Finalizado")             

def ConsultaActualizarTrabajador():

    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )    

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            id=int(input("Ingrese su Rut: "))
            sql="SELECT rut_t, nombre_t, sexo_t, direccion_t, telefono_t, cargo_t, fecha_ing, id_contacto_e, id_carga, id_departamento, id_area FROM trabajador WHERE rut_t="+str(id)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            exec=cursor.fetchone()
            print("Bienvenido {}".format(id))
            print("RUT: ", exec[0])
            print("Nombre: ", exec[1])
            print("Sexo: ", exec[2])
            print("Direccion: ", exec[3])
            print("Telefono: ", exec[4])
            print("Cargo: ", exec[5])
            print("Fecha de ingreso: ", exec[6])
            print("RUT contacto de emergencia: ", exec[7])
            print("RUT carga familiar: ", exec[8])
            print("ID departamento: ", exec[9])
            print("ID area: ", exec[10])
            while True:
                print("""
                ---------------------------------------

                 1- Actualizar Datos personales
                 2- Actualizar Contactos de emergencia
                 3- Actualizar Carga familiar
                 4- Volver

                --------------------------------------- 
                """)
                opt=int(input("Seleccione opcion: "))
                if opt == 1:
                    CambiarDatosPersonales(exec[0])
                elif opt == 2:
                    CambiarContactos(exec[7], exec[0])
                elif opt == 3:
                    CambiarCarga(exec[8], exec[0])
                elif opt == 4:
                    break                
                    


    except Error as er:
        print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("Finalizado")   

def EliminarTrabajador():
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )    

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            rut=input("Ingrese RUT del trabajador: ")
            print("Eliminando registro.....")
            sql="DELETE FROM trabajador WHERE rut_t='{}'".format(rut)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            conexion.commit()
            print("El registro fue eliminado")
           

    except Error as er:
        print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("Accion finalizada")             



def ValidarJefe():
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )    

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            sql="SELECT id_jefe_rrhh, nombre_j FROM jefe_rrhh"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            exec=cursor.fetchone()
            datos_jefe=exec
            conexion.commit()
            return(datos_jefe)
           

    except Error as er:
        print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("Accion finalizada")

def ValidarEmpleadoRRHH():
    try:
        conexion=mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        port=3306,
        password='',
        database='yuri'
        )    

        if conexion.is_connected():
            print("Conexion estable")
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            sql="SELECT rut_rrhh, nombre_rrhh, nombre_j FROM empleado_rrhh INNER JOIN jefe_rrhh ON empleado_rrhh.id_jefe_rrhh=jefe_rrhh.id_jefe_rrhh"
            cursor.execute(sql)
            exec=cursor.fetchone()
            datos_empleado=exec
            conexion.commit()
            return(datos_empleado)
           

    except Error as er:
        print("Error de conexion", er)      

    finally:
        if conexion.is_connected():
            conexion.close
            print("Accion finalizada")                              


while True:
    print("""
    ------------Sistema de listado empresa: El correo de yury-------------

    Ingrese al sistema como:
    1- Jefe RRHH
    2- Empleado RRHH
    3- Salir

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    """)
    opt=int(input("Selecciona una opcion: "))
    if opt == 1:
        datos_jefe=ValidarJefe()
        cuenta_j=input("Ingrese RUT: ")
        if cuenta_j == datos_jefe[0]:
            while True:
                print("""
                -----------Bienvenido-----------
                
                Usuario: {}

                1- Agregar Area
                2- Agregar Deparamento
                3- Ingresar Trabajador
                4- Actulizar Trabajador
                5- Eliminar Trabajador
                6- Consultar Trabajadores
                7- Salir

                ---------------------------------

                """.format(datos_jefe[1]))
                opt=int(input("Selecciona una opcion: "))
                if opt == 1:
                    AlmacenarArea()
                elif opt == 2:
                    AlmacenarDepartamento()
                elif opt == 3:
                    AlmacenarTrabajador()   
                elif opt == 4:
                    ConsultaActualizar()     
                elif opt == 6:
                    print("""
                    -----------------------------

                    1- Listado Trabajadores
                    2- Buscador por Rut
                    3- Lista filtrada

                    -----------------------------
                    """)
                    opt=int(input("Selecciona una opcion: "))
                    if opt == 1:
                        ConsultarTodo()
                    elif opt == 2:
                        ConsultarID()
                        print("1- Volver")
                        opt=int(input("Selecciona la opcion: "))
                    elif opt == 3:
                        ConsultaFiltrada()
                        print("1- Volver")
                        opt=int(input("Selecciona la opcion: "))          
                elif opt == 7:
                    print("Hasta luego")
                    break  
    elif opt == 2:
        datos_empleado=ValidarEmpleadoRRHH()
        cuenta_e = input("Ingrese RUT: ")
        if cuenta_e == datos_empleado[0]:
            while True:
                print("""
                -----------Bienvenido-----------
                
                Usuario: {}
                Jefe a cargo: {}

                1- Listado de trabajadores
                2- Ingresar Trabajador
                3- Actulizar Trabajador
                4- Eliminar Trabajador
                5- Buscar Trabajador
                6- Salir

                ---------------------------------

                """.format(datos_empleado[1], datos_empleado[2]))
                opt=int(input("Selecciona una opcion: "))
                if opt == 1:
                    while True:
                        ConsultarTodo()
                        print("""
                        1- Refrescar
                        2- Volver
                        """)
                        opt = int(input("Seleccione una opcion: "))
                        if opt  == 1:
                            print("Refrescandao....")
                        elif opt == 2:
                            break    
                elif opt == 2:
                    AlmacenarTrabajador()   
                elif opt == 3:
                    ConsultaActualizar()
                elif opt == 4:
                    EliminarTrabajador()         
                elif opt == 5:
                    ConsultarID()
                    print("1- Volver")
                    opt = int(input("Selecciona la opcion: "))         
                elif opt == 6:
                    print("saliendo")
                    break  
    elif opt == 3:
        ConsultaActualizarTrabajador                                        
    elif opt == 4:
        print("programa apagado")
        break
```

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: cual es la salida?

Comment: Estas usando funciones, tienes 15 en ese código y en las 15 estás declarando la conexión a la BD. No estás usando de forma correcta el paradigma funcional. Así como está, el código es mucho más propenso a errores y es más difícil de mantener. Debes crear funciones para que manejen la parte de SQL, una vez que lo logres las llamas desde las otras funciones.